# How to ensure an object is always available in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code in my application layout view that requires an object to exist in order to work. The object exists on some controllers, but not all.

At first I thought I could use the after_filter on the application_controller to ensure that the object exists. But this didn't work because the after_filter is only applied after the view is rendered and it is apparently an [anti-pattern](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2006/12/afterfilter-in-rails-pitfall.html) as well.

What is the best way to ensure that the object always exists, without unnecessarily creating the object on controllers that already create the object.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to ApplicationController? As you might know, every controller in rails inherits from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your variable is @foo.

application_helper.rb

```
def foo
  @foo ||= generate_foo()
end
```

then from any view, you just call your object by foo and not @foo.

Answer (score 0):

This might have it's own pitfalls as well but personally, I will create a method in my `application_controller` to return the instance. To make it available in the views, just pass the method to `helper_method`. `helper_method` is used to share methods between views, helpers and controllers.

I mostly do this with authentication. So you I will have something like;

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

helper_method :current_user # make current_user available in the views
```